# Euler-Maruyama scheme

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can the [Euler-Maruyama method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method) be used to simulate Langevin equations for non-Gaussian white noise? 
I need to evaluate a Langevin equation of the form
$$ dx= a(x)dt+D \eta dt$$
where $\eta$ is a non-Gaussian white noise.

Comment: It's fine.The problem arrives deriving the Fokker-Planck equation, that assumes Gaussian fluctuations.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, stochastic differential equations have no assumptions on distribution of the stochastic variables. However care must be taken for proper solution (Ito/Stratonovich and other perks of multiplicative noise). Also the equivalence of Langevin equation to approptiate Fokker-Plank equation breaks down, as the Fokker-Plank equation assumes Gaussian noise. Colored noise also must be payed special attention.

I recommend the following books for numerical methods of SDE solution -

- Gardiner, Crispin. Stochastic methods. Vol. 4. Berlin: Springer,
  2009
- Kloeden, Peter E., and Eckhard Platen. Numerical solution of
  stochastic differential equations. Vol. 23. Springer Science &
  Business Media, 2013.